# Which are the windows that are in the current workspace?

Tags: unity, windows, workspaces, viewports

is there a way to know easily which are the windows that are placed in the current workspace (unity)?

It seems a stupid question but is not: if a window is behind the others and therefore is not visible, then it's impossible to figure out if that program is on the current workspace or not, unless I decide to move all the windows, which is obviously annoying.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, apt-get upgraded today.

thanks for the answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could install `wmctrl`:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

This is what `apt-cache show wmctrl` has for my system (13.10):

> Description-en: control an EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager
>   Wmctrl is a command line tool to interact with an
>   EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager (examples include
>   Enlightenment, icewm, kwin, metacity, and sawfish).
>   .
>   Wmctrl provides command line access to almost all the features
>   defined in the EWMH specification. For example it can maximize
>   windows, make them sticky, set them to be always on top. It can
>   switch and resize desktops and perform many other useful
>   operations.

Then, `man wmctrl` tells us that the `-l` option will:

> List the windows being managed by the window  manager.  One
>   line  is  output  for  each window, with the line broken up
>   into space separated columns.  The first column always con‐
>   tains the window identity as a hexadecimal integer, and the
>   second column always contains the desktop number (a  -1  is
>   used  to  identify  a  sticky  window). If the -p option is
>   specified the next column will contain the PID for the win‐
>   dow  as  a  decimal  integer. If the -G option is specified
>   then four integer columns will follow: x-offset,  y-offset,
>   width  and  height.  The  next  column  always contains the
>   client machine name. The remainder of the line contains the
>   window title (possibly with multiple spaces in the title).

and that `-x` will

> Include WM_CLASS in the window list or interpret  as the WM_CLASS name.

Here is what I see when I run `wmctrl -lx` with six different applications open:

```
[07:37 AM] ~ $ wmctrl -lx  
0x01c00008 -1 tint2.Tint2                           N/A tint2  
0x02400096  0 Navigator.Firefox     vasa1-Inspiron-1545 12.04 - Which are the windows that are in the current workspace? - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox  
0x02600004  0 Thunar.Thunar         vasa1-Inspiron-1545 _MyMkd - File Manager  
0x01a00004  0 lxterminal.Lxterminal  vasa1-Inspiron-1545 LXTerminal  
0x02200021  0 geany.Geany           vasa1-Inspiron-1545 wmctrl.mkd - /home/vasa1/Dropbox/_MyMkd - Geany  
0x02800003  0 leafpad.Leafpad       vasa1-Inspiron-1545 (Untitled)  
0x02a00003  0 gcolor2.Gcolor2       vasa1-Inspiron-1545 gcolor2  
[07:37 AM] ~ $
```